# Getting the input from user till valid input received

Tags: c#

I am seeking input from user on console

```
            cki = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            string character = cki.KeyChar.ToString();
            if (character == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");
                Name_Updater nu = new Name_Updater();
                nu.Name_Update();
            }
            else if (character == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");
                WCM_Interaction wi = new WCM_Interaction();
                wi.Interact_WCM();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid key! Please try again");
            }
```

but it stops after one iteration, if user enters the invalid input. However I want it to accept inputs from the user till it receives the valid input, but I have confusion on where to place the loop.

Comment: what all are your valid input ?

Comment: use `do while loop`as `do {input} while (false condition)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cki = Console.ReadKey();
string character = cki.KeyChar.ToString();
while (true) // infinite loop
{
        if (character == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");
            Name_Updater nu = new Name_Updater();
            nu.Name_Update();
            break; // break from loop if you read "1"
        }
        if (character == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");
            WCM_Interaction wi = new WCM_Interaction();
            wi.Interact_WCM();
            break;  // break from loop if you read "2"
        }
        // repeat loop if invalid entery
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid key! Please try again");
        cki = Console.ReadKey();
        character = cki.KeyChar.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool correctInput = false;
while (!correctInput)
{
  correctInput = true;

  string decision = Console.ReadLine();
  int iDecision;
  if (int.TryParse(decision, out iDecision))
    switch (iDecision)
    {
      case 0:
        // do something
        break;
      case 1:
        // do something else
        break;
      default:
        correctInput = false;
        break;
    }
  else
    correctInput = false;

  if (!correctInput)
    Console.WriteLine("Tell user their input was bad.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place a do `while` loop to make iterations. It can be embedded as:

```
 cki = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string character;
        bool flag=true;
        do
        {
            character = cki.KeyChar.ToString();
            if (character == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");
                Name_Updater nu = new Name_Updater();
                nu.Name_Update();
                flag=false;
            } 
            else if (character == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");
                WCM_Interaction wi = new WCM_Interaction();
                wi.Interact_WCM();
                flag=false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid key! Please try again");
            }
        }while(flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, what it does is you create a flag, and then set it to true once you satisfy your condition.

```
bool isValid = false;
while (!isValid)
{
    var cki = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("");
    string character = cki.KeyChar.ToString();
    if (character == "1")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");
        //Name_Updater nu = new Name_Updater();
        //nu.Name_Update();
        isValid = true;
    }
    else if (character == "2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");
        //WCM_Interaction wi = new WCM_Interaction();
        //wi.Interact_WCM();
        isValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid key! Please try again");
    }

}
```